# JavaFX app is lagging using multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx-8

I have app which aim is to simulate race of N racers(threads). Running this app on my desktop with Win10 works perfectly, however on my notebook with Ubuntu 18.04 app is lagging dramaticlly.

I'm not sure about cause of this situation, but I guess it can be something wrong with my code. Every single thread is called by Executor Service in controller and threads are represented in UI by ProgressBars. I read a lot of topic with same problems here and I changed my Call() method. Namely, I have implemented Platform.runLater() to update my ProgressBars there, but unfortunately it haven't changed anything.

```
public Boolean call() {
    try {
        for (double i = 0; i < getRaceTime(); i += 0.01) {
            final double counter = i;
            final double range = getRaceTime();

            Platform.runLater(() ->  progressBar.setProgress(counter / range));

            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1);

        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return true;
}
```

I hope that somebody could explain me where I am wrong or what is reaseon of this terrible lags?

EDIT:
Methods where I'm starting threads:

```
public void startButtonClicked() {
    for (RallyRacer r : rallyRacers) {
        futures.add(executorService.submit(r));
    }
    new Thread(task).start();

    executorService.shutdown();
}

public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    this.executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15);
    this.futures = new ArrayList<>();
    this.rallyRacers = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        rallyRacers.add(new RallyRacer());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how are you starting the threads?

Comment: is the 'call' method inside a background thread?

Comment: `getRaceTime()` doesn't happen to require synchroniation with the JavaFX application thread? How about `RallyRacer`? BTW: Running 17 threads in parallel could be a problem for certain machines... Also calculating the progress to submit could easily be done in the loop body reducing the required number of `final` variables by 1.

Comment: RallyRacer is class which implements Callable and call() method above is from RallyRacer. Problem is solved when my incrementation in loop is something like 0.5 or more, but it is easy to recognize that ProgressBars are less animated.
And @fabian, you're right with number of final variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is mostly about tracking/displaying the progress of the racers on the UI, I would recommend thinking about a longer sleep time:

1. The human eye does not recognize visual changes at the speed of 1 ms. At this point I would go a number of changes per second that is something like the usual frame rate of a movie. That would be at least 20 frames (i.e. updates or new images) per second up to some 50 or 60 for high visual performance.
2. JavaFX uses it's own "frame rate". The JavaFX framework updates the UI state about 60 times/second - not more. Thus, it is simply overkill to update a progress bar 1000 times a second.

Maybe you want to try sleep times of ten or 20 ms, or even more. I would gess, the overall performance of the app improves.

Comment: Ok, so I understand that I have to fiddle with longer Thread sleep time, bigger loop incrementation and reduce number of final variables and rest my solutions of my problem are acceptable?

Comment: As for the simple, low-level Java multithreading, it looks quite good, but I would have to see the whole code to give a valid statement.

Comment: In general, it is important not to manipulate the UI from outside the UI thread. That is, what PLatform.runLater() does, so this is fine. JavaFX would throw an Exception anyway.

Comment: If you use JavaFX Tasks (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html), it would provide a more elegant solution: JavaFX Tasks have a progress property and a message property that may be bound directly to likewise properties of UI controls. So, you wouldn't have to call  Platform.runLater().